# Know if items have been pushed

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the following code that executes JS files that make HTTP calls and return files, if these files are different from those that already exist, they are pushed.

Everything works, but I would like to make sure that when there is a change in a file it will notify me by sending me a notification on discord.

I tried printing the `github.event_name`, but it prints `schedule` whether files are modified or not.

```yaml
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0,12 * * *'
name: Init
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: Install
      run: npm install
    - name: One
      run: npm run action 
    - uses: mikeal/publish-to-github-action@master
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    - name: Two
      run: npm run visit 
    - uses: mikeal/publish-to-github-action@master
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    - name: Test
      run: echo ${{ github.event_name }}
    - name: Send Discord Notification
      if: github.event_name == 'push'
      run: |
        curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
          -d '{"content": "A commit has been made on the repository."}' \
          ${{ secrets.DISCORD_WEBHOOK_URL }}
```

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: _"it prints `schedule` whether files are modified or not"_ - ...yes? You _only_ trigger that workflow on a schedule, not when changes are pushed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: In fact I need to understand how I can understand if there have been any changes.

Comment: Presumably if there _are_ changes there's a `git diff` before you try to commit and push those changes. Or you could actually _trigger on the event you care about_.

Answer (score 0):

Your triggers section `on:` only lists a schedule, so this workflow will only ever trigger on a schedule.

If you want it to trigger every time a commit is pushed you'll need to add `push:` to your triggers like so:

```
on:
  push:
```

If you want to list the changed files on a schedule, you'll need to compare the files between the current workflow run and the previous one. There are actions on the marketplace that can help you get those changes. [Here is one action that you might be able to use](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/changed-files).

```
      - name: Get changed files
        id: changed-files
        uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v40
        
        # To compare changes between the current commit and the last pushed remote commit set `since_last_remote_commit: true`. e.g
        # with:
        #   since_last_remote_commit: true 

      - name: List all changed files
        run: |
          for file in ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }}; do
            echo "$file was changed"
          done
```